# Many table columns with getter and setter

Tags: arraylist, javafx, tableview, getter-setter, tablecolumn

I know if I have 2 columns, I have to set getter and setter like below

```
private SimpleIntegerProperty num;
private SimpleStringProperty name;

public GradeCat1st1(){
    this.num = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty();
}

public GradeCat1st1(Integer num, String name){
    this.num = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num);
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
}

public Integer getNum(){
    return num.get();
}

public void setNum(Integer num){
    this.num.set(num);
}

public String getName(){
    return name.get();
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name.set(name);
}
```

Here's call to propertyvalue code.

```
tcName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
tcNum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("num"));
```

But what if I have more than 10 or 20 columns, do I have to put each columns getter and setter?

I'd like to make something like arraylist of simpleStringproperty but have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

By using a custom `cellValueFactory` you could retrieve the data from a custom data structure.

I recommend using a `ObservableList` and retrieve data using the `Bindings` class. The following example also shows how to make the table editable.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C"),
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("D")
    ));
    // find size of longest list
    final int columns = table.getItems().stream().mapToInt(ObservableList::size).max().orElse(0);

    table.setEditable(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>("column "+i);
        column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        final int index = i;

        // use index in list corresponding to column index
        column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.valueAt(cd.getValue(), index));

        // write to index on a commit
        // (necessary, since Bindingx.valueAt doesn't return a WritableValue)
        column.setOnEditCommit(evt -> {
            ObservableList<String> item = evt.getRowValue();
            String newValue = evt.getNewValue();
            if (item.size() <= index) {
                // pad with null
                for (int j = item.size(); j < index; j++) {
                    item.add(null);
                }

                item.add(newValue);
            } else {
                item.set(index, newValue);
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    // button for printing the contents to console to show the lists are updated
    Button btn = new Button("Print");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println(table.getItems());
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(table, btn));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```